# How to override JS file via YAML deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, deployment, yaml

I face one issue and I don't know the solution for this. Normally I use microsoft/variable-substitution@v1 to overwrite parameters inside json file. But now I have one js file like below.

```
module.exports = {
  server: "",
  port: 1433,
  database: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true
  }
}
```

and I want to fill data from github secrets via YAML file to deploy aplication.Below code is for  one step inside yaml file

```
- name: Database Connection Variable Substitution
        uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with:
          files: './server/config/dbConnection.js'
        env:
          server: ${{ secrets.DB_SERVER }}
          database: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
          user: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
```

but it doesn't work and I understood that we can use this library for only json and xml, Is there any way yo overwrite also js files?

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, the microsoft/variable-substitution task can only be used to overwrite parameters inside JSON and XML files, and not JavaScript files. One possible solution is to use a script task to modify the JavaScript file during the pipeline run. You can use a combination of shell commands and environment variables to achieve this. Example below-

Comment: `- script: |
    sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER/$(MY_SECRET)/g" myscript.js
  env:
    MY_SECRET: $(my_secret)`

Comment: the sed command is used to replace the string "PLACEHOLDER" in the myscript.js file with the value of the MY_SECRET environment variable. The MY_SECRET environment variable is set to the value of the my_secret pipeline variable using the syntax $(my_secret).